# Is "on lunch" truly correct?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I have followed a few discussions about whether "on lunch", as opposed to "at lunch", is correct.

One opinion stated that "on lunch" indicates a status (on leave, on break) while "at lunch" is more likely conveying a sense of a person eating in a physical location.
Thus, I do not know whether "on lunch" is grammatically correct or it is just an informal, shortened version for "on lunch break".

Comment: This US English speaker has never heard anybody say "on lunch", and it sounds like a mistake to me.  It could be part of "on lunch *break*", but in that phrasing, *lunch* is just being used as an adjective to *break*.

Comment: In the UK, I've only heard "at lunch".

Comment: This [(Ngram)] (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+lunch%2Cat+lunch&year_start=1800&year_end=2018&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20lunch%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20lunch%3B%2Cc0) shows 'at lunch' to be many times more common than 'on lunch'. However, 'on lunch' does appear to have been in use from as far back as 1860. I suspect that 'on lunch' was originally a lexical error based on 'on duty' and, with time, it is gradually becoming more common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a  work context:

To be on a break, to be on a lunch or tea break, but: to be at lunch.

- He is **on his [lunch,tea,etc.] break**.
- **He is at lunch**.

In short, the guy's out of the office.